# Keybinding in VSC for scroll cursor to next/last method in the code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In the old visual studio, there was such a combination of keys ctrl+up/down, and can I configure the VSC to quick jump from one method to next/last in the code?